Methods of dynamic type reassignment?
I've been thinking lately about how I could reassign types to pointers after erasure (being cast as a void pointer). Here is a method I came up with earlier today:
#include<stdio.h>

//represent all possible types to be reassigned
typedef enum types {STRUCT_ONE, STRUCT_TWO, STRUCT_THREE} types;

typedef struct struct_one {
    enum types type;
    int val1;
    double val2;
} struct_one;

typedef struct struct_two {
    enum types type;
    char val1;
    void* val2;
} struct_two;

typedef struct struct_three {
    enum types type;
    long val1;
    int  val2[10];
} struct_three;

void reassign(void*);

int main() {
    struct_one first;
    first.type = STRUCT_ONE;   //This member will be used to reassign original type
    first.val1 = 64;
    first.val2 = 1.2;

    struct_two second;
    second.type = STRUCT_TWO;
    second.val1 = 'b';
    second.val2 = &first;

    struct_three third;
    third.type = STRUCT_THREE;
    third.val1 = 1;
    third.val2[3] = 3;

    reassign(&first);
    reassign(&second);
    reassign(&third);

    return 0;
}

void reassign(void* some_struct) {
    types* t = some_struct;    //works only if the first member is a type enum

    switch(*t) {
        case STRUCT_ONE:
            struct_one* my_struct1 = some_struct;
            printf("%d\t%lf\n", my_struct1 -> val1, my_struct1 -> val2);
            break;

        case STRUCT_TWO:
            struct_two* my_struct2 = some_struct;
            printf("%c\t%p\n", my_struct2 -> val1, my_struct2 -> val2);
            break;

        case STRUCT_THREE:
            struct_three* my_struct3 = some_struct;
            printf("%ld\t%d\n", my_struct3 -> val1, my_struct3 -> val2[3]);
            break;
    }
    return;
}

To sumurarize, the enum at the top represents all possible types that need to be reassigned. The corresponding enum is set as the first member of each struct. This is because (in gcc at least,) structs have no headers, ergo struct pointers are pointers to their first member. Even after being cast as a void pointer, that pointer will still point to the enum, and it can therefore be used to determine the struct's original type.
Output:
64  1.200000
b   0x7ffc9be166e0
1   3

This seems to work as intended, but is is not very dynamic. I would have to identify beforehand all the possible types that could be passed into the function. Unfortunately as far as I know, there isn't a way in C to reference type as a discrete value (at least, not while using gcc), so it wouldn't be possible to do something like: if(get_type(operand) == get_type(int)). Elsewise, I could perhaps set the first member of the structs as the type itself, and cast each struct by the type contained in their first member. Something along these lines:
typedef struct struct_one {
    Type t;
} struct_one;

int main() {
    struct_one mystruct;
    mystruct.t = struct_one;
    reassign(&mystruct);
    return 0;
}

void reassign(void* some_struct) {
    Type* t = some_struct;
    typeof *t my_struct = some_struct;
    return;
}

My question is, is a facsimile of this even possible, even if not as written?
I admit being rather new to C, so perhaps there's some operator or compiler directive I'm unaware of that could help? Didn't see anything while combing through K&R though. Is there any way I could modify my code so that it can cast the void pointer back to any type at all, not just the ones defined in my enum?
I tried using the typeof operator, but found that it didn't work the way I though. Tried finding a way to store a data type as a variable, but other sources on the web say that isn't possible. Tried identifying types by size, but realized how bad of an idea that would be.

You're on the right track with type as the first element of the structs. You can use void * and switch (type) / case, but there are cleaner ways to do this. What you probably want is the "vtable" approach. For a discussion and [progressive] examples of methods to do this, see my answer: Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C

The C standard does not provide any run-time introspection for types other than some very limited cases, such as getting the size of a variable-length array. Distinguishing types at run time has to be done with a mechanism like the one you show. However, it has to be done carefully, with knowledge of the rules about aliasing and other rules of C. The code you show looks okay to largely due to a rule about converting a pointer to a structure to a pointer to the type of its first member.

Type-generic programming in C is clunky and works best when there is an actual problem to solve, rather than just making things type-generic for the heck of it. The old school way is indeed to use enums + void pointers. Newer C standards support _Generic and typeof which can be used for determining types at compile-time. There's no run-time way ("RTTI") other than coding it yourself with enums etc. You can however cook up something crude which works similar to C++ templates: generating code according to which types that are present at compile-time.

Another old-school way is to use callbacks, as done in bsearch/qsort.

Considering these 3 struct
typedef struct
{
    int    val1;
    double val2;
} One;


typedef struct
  {
    char  val1;
    void* val2;
} Two;

typedef struct
{
    long val1;
    int  val2[10];
} Three;

If we can have a header to signal the type of the struct that follows, this is a common case in networking, where a header identifies the message body. I will show a few common ways to process the rest of the message, in an example below.
I will also use a function table and a selector function. As I am coding along this may get a bit long and boring. You can jump to "complete code" below.
A struct Buffer
typedef struct
{
   int32_t id;
   int (*show)(void*);
   union {
    One one;
    Two two;
    Three three; 
   };
}  Buffer;

This uses an id field, a pointer to a show function, and a union representing the 3 struct. At any time id can be evaluated and a show method can be assigned along wih the required fields, based on id.
using a struct Three
    Buffer b3 =
    {
        .id = S_THREE,
        .three.val1 = 17, 
        .three.val2= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 },
        .show = show_31        
    };

As an example, b3 sets up the id and fields for a Three struct. The show methods are declared
int show_11(void*);
int show_12(void*);
int show_21(void*);
int show_31(void*);
// takes a void* and call method based on header 'id'
int show(void* addr);

And uses the expected fields and structs. See the code
Since the expect mehod is loaded as a field in Buffer it can be called in 2 ways:
    show_31(&b3); // will use show31()
    b3.show(&b3);

using a VFT
    // using a VFT
    int (*F[3])(void*) =  {NULL};
    F[S_ONE] =   show_12;
    F[S_TWO] =   show_21;
    F[S_THREE] = show_31;

This builds a table that can be used as
    F[ b1.id ](&b1);
    F[ b2.id ](&b2);
    F[ b3.id ](&b3);  

using Buffer as a void* in a selector function
int show(void* addr)
{
    ((Buffer*)addr)->show(addr);
    return 0;
}

This uses addr as a pointer to Buffer and calls the show mehod, but could insteat use a function pointer table based on the id field.
ouput

        Version 1 struct type 1
        int val1 is 42, double val2 is 42.42

        Version 2 struct type 1
        (int) val1 is 0000000042, double val2 is  42.4200

        Version 1, struct type 2
        char val1 is '?', void* val2 points to 00000000  

        Version 1, struct type 2
        char val1 is '?', void* val2 points to 00000000  

        Version 1, struct type 3
        int val1 = 17
        int[10] val2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

        Version 1, struct type 3
        int val1 = 17
        int[10] val2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}


***** now uses a function table to call a method based on the 'id' field *****


        Version 2 struct type 1
        (int) val1 is 0000000042, double val2 is  42.4200

        Version 1, struct type 2
        char val1 is '?', void* val2 points to 00000000

        Version 1, struct type 3
        int val1 = 17
        int[10] val2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}


***** now uses a void* pointer and calls the 'show' method' *****


        Version 2 struct type 1
        (int) val1 is 0000000042, double val2 is  42.4200

        Version 1, struct type 2
        char val1 is '?', void* val2 points to 00000000

        Version 1, struct type 3
        int val1 = 17
        int[10] val2 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

complete code for the example
#pragma pack(show)
#pragma pack(push,4)
#pragma pack(show)

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

typedef enum  {S_ONE,S_TWO,S_THREE} types;

typedef struct
{
    int    val1;
    double val2;
} One;


typedef struct
  {
    char  val1;
    void* val2;
} Two;

typedef struct
{
    long val1;
    int  val2[10];
} Three;

typedef struct
 {
   int32_t id;
   int (*show)(void*);
   union {
    One one;
    Two two;
    Three three; 
   };
}  Buffer;

int show_11(void*);
int show_12(void*);
int show_21(void*);
int show_31(void*);
// takes a void* and call method based on header 'id'
int show(void* addr);

int main()
{
    Buffer b1 =
    {
        .id = S_ONE,
        .one.val1 = 42,
        .one.val2=42.42,
        .show = show_12
    };
    show_11(&b1);
    b1.show(&b1); // will use show12()

    Buffer b2 =
    { 
        .id = S_TWO,
        .two.val1 = '?',
        .two.val2=NULL,
        .show=show_21
    };
    show_21(&b2);
    b2.show(&b2); // will use show21()

    Buffer b3 =
    {
        .id = S_THREE,
        .three.val1 = 17, 
        .three.val2= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 },
        .show = show_31        
    };
    show_31(&b3); // will use show31()
    b3.show(&b3);

    printf("\n\n***** now uses a function table to call a method based on the 'id' field *****\n\n");

    // using a VFT
    int (*F[3])(void*) =  {NULL};
    F[S_ONE] =   show_12;
    F[S_TWO] =   show_21;
    F[S_THREE] = show_31;
    // call correct 'show' function based on the 'id' field    
    F[ b1.id ](&b1);
    F[ b2.id ](&b2);
    F[ b3.id ](&b3);  

    printf("\n\n***** now uses a void* pointer and calls the 'show' method' *****\n\n");
    show((void*) &b1);
    void* pThing = &b2;
    show(pThing);
    show(&b3);
    
    return 0;
}


int show_11(void* p)
{
    One* one = &((Buffer*)p)->one;
    printf( "\n\
        Version 1 struct type 1\n\
        int val1 is %d, double val2 is %g\n", 
        one->val1, one->val2);
    return 0;
}

int show_12(void* p)
{
    One* one = &((Buffer*)p)->one;
    printf( "\n\
        Version 2 struct type 1\n\
        (int) val1 is %010d, double val2 is %8.4f\n", 
        one->val1, one->val2);
    return 0;
}

int show_21(void* p)
{
    Two* t = &((Buffer*)p)->two;
    printf( "\n\
        Version 1, struct type 2\n\
        char val1 is '%c', void* val2 points to %p\n", 
        t->val1, t->val2);
    return 0;
}

int show_31(void* p)
{
    Three* t = &((Buffer*)p)->three;
    printf( "\n\
        Version 1, struct type 3\n\
        int val1 = %d\n\
        int[10] val2 = {", 
        t->val1);
    for(int i=0;i<9;i+=1) printf("%d,",t->val2[i]);
    printf("%d}\n", t->val2[9]);    
    return 0;
}

int show(void* addr)
{
    ((Buffer*)addr)->show(addr);
    return 0;
}

Choose the part that goes with your case.
